# How to set off a Spring WebFlow transition in javascript

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a Spring WebFlow2 project that if the user clicks the "loadschools" submit button I will call to my controller and load the states and then redisplay the same screen with the new states based on a radio button that is selected.  I would like to remove the "loadschool" submit button and have java script run if the user clicks a radio button.  can this be done? how do I tell webflow the transition to run?

```
<view-state id="SchoolVisitReport" view="SchoolVisitReport.jsp" model="visit" >
 <transition on="submit" to="addVisit">
   <evaluate expression="flowActions.validateVisit(visit, messageContext)"/>
 </transition>
 <transition on="cancel" to="endState" bind="false"/>
 <transition on="loadSchools" to="SchoolVisitReport" >
    <evaluate expression="flowActions.initializeSelectableStates(visit)" result="flowScope.selectableStates"/>
 </transition>
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onchange='window.location="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=loadSchools"'`

Comment: try to put it on both the onclick and on the onchange

Comment: <form:radiobutton tabIndex="9" onchange='window.location="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=loadSchools")' onclick='window.location="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=loadSchools")' value="B" path="borough" />Bronx-X<BR>

Comment: oups my bad, there is a ')' that has nothing to do here. try with the edited code

Comment: yea. I was just thinking that we have to change the eventId then submit the form.. can you help with that?

Comment: well, this is now resolved, so you should accept my answer and write a new question with more details on what you want to do next

Comment: I will but it will not let me post the new question. can you please help me and I give you full credit

Answer (score 0):

for your second issue, try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
                        elementId : "radiobuttonId",
                        formId : "visitFormId",
                        event : "onChange",
                        params : {
                            _eventId : "loadSchools",
                            fragments : "body"
                        }
                    }));
                </script>
```

and see if the form gets submitted

Comment: where do I put this and how do I call this

Comment: you can put this anywhere in your jsp file. just replace 'radiobuttonId' by your radiobutton id, 'visitFormId' by your form id.
it is going to be called automatically